# How to output a full table of results from a nested triple for loop through pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas, function, for-loop, nested-loops

I have written a function to calculate the gradient between two columns of two dataframes and output this gradient in a new dataframe. These columns have the same headings, and upon merging the columns a suffix of _A or _B is added.

The column headings are chemical formulas, the table output is expected to be in dataframe columns where there is a gradient of the linear regression between two columns for the same chemical formula from two dataframes.

The input dataframes contains columns with chemical formula headings, integer values in each of the columns and are indexed with a datetimeindex.

```
def find_gradient(dfA, dfB):

dfA.resample('1min')
dfB.resample('1min')

combined_df = dfA.merge(dfB,how='inner',left_index=True,right_index=True, suffixes=('_A', "_B"))
combined_df= combined_df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)

#return combined_df

listofcols = combined_df.columns
listofcols = listofcols.tolist()

listofformulas = dfA.columns
listofformulas = listofformulas.tolist()


for cols in listofcols:
for formula in listofformulas: 

    A = [col for col in combined_df if col.startswith(formula) and col.endswith('_A')]#.str] # startswith(formula)
    B = [col for col in combined_df if col.startswith(formula) and col.endswith('_B')]#.str] #startswith(formula)

    q1 = combined_df[A]
    q2 = combined_df[B]

    x1 = np.squeeze(np.array(q1))
    x2 = np.squeeze(np.array(q2))

    gradient = np.polyfit(x1,x2,0) ## fits a linear regression and forces the y-intercept to 0


    GradientFormulas = pd.DataFrame(columns=['formula','gradient'])
    GradientFormulas = GradientFormulas.append([{'formula':formula,'gradient':gradient}])

    return GradientFormulas
```

The output is expected to be a table with as many rows as there are chemical formulas (columns in input) and a single gradient value corresponding to each row. However, the output currently only shows the chemical formula and gradient for the first column.

Comment: This is a **triple for loop**! For loops are evil. Avoid for loops in python at all cost. This can be vectorized easily.

Comment: @AM94 The return statement is inside for loop. This might be the problem. Furthermore, you problem with the indentation in produced code.